# Android JavaX-Mail Having SSL-Handshake-Exception

Tags: java, android, email, ssl, jakarta-mail

Hope you all are safe. Recently I have implemented **JavaX mail** in my application. When I have implemented this code was working fine I was getting mails from my **Webmail**. But after few days I tried to run this code again, it start giving me the **exceptions**. I have checked the `server-side` nothing is changed. Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem.

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }
    private final String user;
    private final String password;
    private final Session session;

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "xtenxion.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "xtenxion.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized Boolean sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(recipients));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);
            Log.e("SendMail","message sent successfully....");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Having this **exception**:

> 2021-04-29 16:05:11.810 14664-15084/com.xtenxion.letsplayqna
> E/SendMail: Could not connect to SMTP host: xtenxion.com, port: 465
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xtenxion.com, port: 465;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
> at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
> at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.mail.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:56)
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.activities.ForgetPassword_One_Activity$1$1.doInBackground(ForgetPassword_One_Activity.java:86)
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.activities.ForgetPassword_One_Activity$1$1.doInBackground(ForgetPassword_One_Activity.java:73)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:351)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:665)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:627)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:1449)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1366)
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412) 
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310) 
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169) 
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118) 
> at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188) 
> at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118) 
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.mail.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:56) 
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.activities.ForgetPassword_One_Activity$1$1.doInBackground(ForgetPassword_One_Activity.java:86) 
> at com.xtenxion.letsplayqna.activities.ForgetPassword_One_Activity$1$1.doInBackground(ForgetPassword_One_Activity.java:73) 
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345) 
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

**UPDATE**:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    private final Session session;

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "xtenxion.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "xtenxion.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(true);
    }



    public synchronized Boolean sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);
            Log.e("SendMail", "message sent successfully....");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendMail", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**Exception**:

> Error Could not connect to SMTP host: xtenxion.com, port: 465

I tried several code to connect with my **Webmail** but still failed. The Webmail address I'm using is **ahmad@xtenxion.com**.I don't know what's wrong and how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I access Gmail with Jakarta Mail?](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ.html#gmail):

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String username = "user";
String password = "passwd";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
// set any other needed mail.smtp.* properties here
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// set the message content here
Transport.send(msg, username, password);
```

The dot protocol properties should be `smtps` and `imaps`.  However you shouldn't need to set them at all.  Just remove them.  The `xtenxion.com` ssl certificate needs to be added to your truststore.

Comment: my mail address which is I'm using to send mail is from My WebMail like: ahmad@xtenxion.com that why I think we need xtenxion.com ssl certificate?

Comment: You will need the ssl cert in your truststore to establish the connection. Using mail.smtp.ssl.trust property should allow you to avoid that.  The best practice is to just load the cert in the truststore.

Comment: OK, I got your point. If I use non-ssl host for mail it will work right?

Comment: That would work too.  Then you don't need any of the ssl properties or smtps/imaps properties.

Comment: Is that reliable. Does it will effect in future or not?

Comment: It is reliable it is just not secure.

Comment: Can you explain not secure means?

Comment: [Difference between SMTP and smtps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS)